# Is it too resource intensive to have a server Merge PDFs for Users?

Tags: performance, pdf-generation, pdfbox, merging-data

I am doing some research, trying to find out if its a good or bad idea to do the following.

1. A user would make a selection of choices
2. Based on the selections, our website would merge these selected PDFs together
3. The user could download the Merged PDF.

I know there are things like "Java Open Source PDF Libraries" and "PDFBox", but my main question is this…

Would this be too server intensive?

Comment: *too server intensive* - what are your resources, what is your expected volume of merge requests, what kind of source PDFs are we talking about?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how often the operation will be run, and how much money you are willing to spend on hardware. I suggest you estimate the expected load and run a benchmark.